# Profiling a Jar's Memory and CPU Usage

Tags: java, memory-management, jar, jvm, cpu-usage

When running a Java jar application, what's the best way to benchmark the CPU and memory usage accurately? I'm currently using VisualVM but I want a plugin or something that I can attach to the pom or project if possible.

Additional: How about in a serverless app like Spring?

Comment: With spring boot at least, you can use actuator.

You can see this link:

https://medium.com/@brunosimioni/near-real-time-monitoring-charts-with-spring-boot-actuator-jolokia-and-grafana-1ce267c50bcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Spring Boot Actuator](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) for monitoring. Add **spring-boot-starter-actuator** dependency, configure application.properties or .yaml file and you can see cpu usage with HTTP request.

Also java provide this structure with [MXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html). If you want you can create your own MBean server and show CPU usage on jconsole.

```
public void exampleCPUUsageWithMXBean() {
    long previousJvmProcessCpuTime = 0;
    long previousJvmUptime = 0;
    com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean prepareOperatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(OperatingSystemMXBean.class);
    java.lang.management.OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

    long elapsedProcessCpuTime = prepareOperatingSystemMXBean.getProcessCpuTime() - previousJvmProcessCpuTime;
    // elapsed uptime is in milliseconds
    long elapsedJvmUptime = runtimeMXBean.getUptime() - previousJvmUptime;

    // total jvm uptime on all the available processors
    long totalElapsedJvmUptime = elapsedJvmUptime * operatingSystemMXBean.getAvailableProcessors();

    float cpuUsage = elapsedProcessCpuTime / (totalElapsedJvmUptime * 10000F);

    System.out.println(cpuUsage);

}
```

**Note:** I recommend [Java Mission Control](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) tool. This tool very useful and showing all details.